# clicking on mat-select option element register as outside click using hostlistiner in angular 8

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, html-select

I want to create an inline table editing feature, so that when you click on a field you can edit it, and when you click outside of the table, the editing is done.

I use mat-select element to create multiple selection:

```
<mat-form-field id="selectAndOptionsContainer" class="form-element">
  <mat-select id="selectContainer" [(ngModel)]="Obj['index']"
   placeholder="Select Indices" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let index of indices"
    [value]="index">{{index}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

I use the HostListener decorator in angular like so:

```
public onClick(targetElement){
  const clickedInside = this._elementRef.nativeElement.contains(targetElement);
  if (!clickedInside) {
    console.log(`clicked OUtside`);
  }
}
```

This hostlistener is on the componenet ts file, where the assosiated HTML file includes the entire tabel and the select part in it.

When I click on the table lines, no event is triggered.

When I click on element outside of my table - no event is triggered.

When I click on the "select" section (which after the options list is shown) - no event is triggered.

When I click on the options in the options list - the event is triggered.

Why does the "option" HTML element registers as being outside?

I checked the source code, and it seems the the options elements are not rendered before clicking the "select" element, and this might be the heart of the problem.

Is there a way to make the options element to appear in the DOM before clicking select, but still be hidden?

When I user default HTML multiple select, the click event is not firing when I select options.

Comment: Your problem is that the `mat-select` is rendered in the `cdk-overlay-container` and you are listening to the host `app-root`. You can try to check if the click was in the `cdk-overlay-container` and then ignore that click. https://puu.sh/EwjRU/8184413ed5.png